# X++ doesn't skip AOS validation when it should

Tags: validation, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I've created a custom batchable class that is normally ran by a menu item calling SysOperationServiceController with the custom class name as the parameter.  The custom class is marked as RunOn Server.  In the code that I'm executing, I'm trying to delete a LogisticsLocation record, however, it's failing with error: "Cannot delete a record in Addresses (LogisticsPostalAddress).
The corresponding AOS validation failed." After stepping thru the logic of LogisticsPostalAddress.aosValidateDelete() code, I've found no good reason why this should fail, but this is not the reason for my question.

My goal is to attempt to bypass this AOS validation by logisticsLocation.skipAOSValidation(true).  After working around the permission violation errors that I was getting, I found that I had to assert a SkipAOSValidationPermission first before skipping AOS validation.  However, even though I do this, the aosValidateDelete() logic is still being hit.  I'm also trying to avoid doing logisiticsLocation.doDelete() because I do want it to before the standard DeleteAction logic and cascade down to also delete the corresponding records.

Ultimately, my goal is to delete this record without error.  And I cannot see any reason why it should fail, there is a DeleteAction with a Restricted option on LogisticsPostalAddress, however, it's for a table that doesn't have a relating record for.  The logic inside LogisticsPostalAddress.aosValidateDelete() doesn't make sense altogether, which is why I'm looking to bypass.  So my real question remains, why does it still attempt to AOS validate when I specifically tell it not to and I've jumped thru all the security hoops to do so?  And how do I really skip this validation?

My Code:

```
while select dirPartyPostalAddressView
    where dirPartyPostalAddressView.Party == dirPartyRecId //some local variable established earlier
join forUpdate logisticsLocation
    where logisticsLocation.RecId == dirPartyPostalAddressView.Location
{
    if (isRunningOnServer())
    {
        CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
        skipValidPermission = new SkipAOSValidationPermission();
        skipValidPermission.assert();

        logisticsLocation.skipAosValidation(true);
    }

    logisticsLocation.delete();
}
```

Comment: You're skipping validation on `LogisticsLocation`, but the failing validation is on `LogisticsPostalAddress`.
By the way, the check for `isRunningOnServer()` suggests that you sometimes run it on client, which is very inefficient. I strongly recommend running it always on server.

Comment: I only run it on the client when I need to debug it and breakpoint thru it, and the SkipAOSValidation permission fails if it executes on the client.  But, any ideas on how to pass the skip validation thru?  The logic in LogisiticsPostalAddress.skipAOSValidateDelete doesn't make any sense, I can't see a scenario where this would return true.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question or create a new question to explain what exactly does not make sense to you in `LogisticsPostalAddress.skipAOSValidateDelete`?